# How does agnes() in R treat factor columns?

Tags: r, dendrogram

I'm new to R, and I haven't seen this discussed anywhere, so I'm only 95% confident of my results.

Reading the `agnes()` documentation, I see that in the input "matrix or data frame, each row corresponds to an observation, and each column corresponds to a variable. **All variables must be numeric**."

I have been working with a large dataset containing survey responses from 144 countries. I created a data frame with a Country name column and several columns representing the averages of normalized numeric variables (range 0-1) for that country (one row per country). I used that data frame as the input to `agnes()`, and I noticed that the resulting dendrogram showed the countries in alphabetical order.

Code:

```
Calculate the average value for each numeric variable for each country.
wm <- aggregate(wd2[!names(wd2) %in% c("Country")], list(Country=wd2$Country), mean)

Create dendrogram.
w_dendc <- agnes(wm,method="complete",diss = FALSE, stand = FALSE)
pltree(w_dendw,labels = wm$Country)
```

This made no sense, so I scoured the documentation and found the quote above. It certainly looked like `agnes()` converted the country names into numeric values 1-144. Because that was by far the largest distance measure, it overwhelmed the other variables and resulted in the alphabetized result.

So I tried again leaving out the Country column and simply using the Country as the label source in `pltree()`. When I did that, the dendrogram had some very interesting features, and the countries seemed to be grouped by some combination of geographic proximity and educational/economic attainment.

```
Create dendrogram, leaving out the Country column (first column).
w_dendc <- agnes(wm[,-1],method="complete",diss = FALSE, stand = FALSE)
pltree(w_dendw,labels = wm$Country)
```

I'm simply asking for validation that my interpretation is correct about `agnes()` and the use of factor variables like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the source code it appears that you are correct. The data are converted using `data.matrix()` which converts factors to their numeric representation. Just try `x <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=6:10, c=LETTERS[1:5])` followed by `data.matrix(x)`. Note that if you used `daisy()` to convert the data to a dissimilarity matrix before running `agnes()`, the factor variable would be treated as categorical data and the dissimilarity measure would be gower.

Comment: @dcarlson I believe you have confirmed my experience. If you want to propose that as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `agnes()` function converts the data using `data.matrix()` which converts factors to numeric data. The solution is to exclude the country column from your analysis as you suggest.

Comment: I want to reiterate the answerer's "proof" from their comment to my OP: "Just try x <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=6:10, c=LETTERS[1:5]) followed by data.matrix(x)."